# Обявление Function Declaration в ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Хотел спросить про **Классическу объявление функции** (FUNCTION DECLARATION)  в Ecmascript6.

Очень часто встречаю такого вида записей функции в ES6

```
let logMessage = message => {
    // etc
}
```

Такого рода объявление функции называется функциональным выражением (FUNCTION EXPRESSION) .
Но не где не нашел алтернативу.Вoзможно ли в ES6 обявить функцию как **function declaration** И как это сделать приведите пример пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявления функций из языка никуда не пропали, что можно увидеть в пункте [14.1 Function Definitions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) стандарта:

```
// function declaration
function logMessage (message) {
    // ...
}

// function expression
const logMessage = function (message) {
    // ...
}
```

Кстати, приведенная вами конструкция функциональным выражением не является. Стрелочные функции описаны в отдельном разделе стандарта - [14.2 Arrow Function Definitions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions)

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ @Pavel Mayorov

Answer (score -3):

В ES6 стрелочную функцию невозможно объявить как **function declaration**. Стрелочные функции не являются заменой **function declarations** and **function expressions**, которые до сих пор используются и присутствуют в ES6 стандарте.

Функцию как **function declarations** вы можете объявить как обычно:

```
function logMessage (message) {
    // ...
}
```

Стрелочные функции - это новый синтаксис функций с другим поведением.
Прочитайте подробнее про стрелочные функции в [документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).